# Taking Output and Inputting it

Tags: python, parsing, input, python-imaging-library, output

Im writing a program that takes my school grades and makes them my desktop background when the program parses my grades from the site it returns them all as one

Code that retrieves grades from the school grade site:

```
for cell in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".grid tr a[href$='fg=S2']"):
    print cell.text
```

cell.text comes back as

```
--
B
84
--
A-
90
--
C+
79
--
A
95
--
B
82
--
B
81
```

but then i need to input it back into the image for my desktop BG

```
font = ImageFont.load_default() 
img = Image.open('bg.bmp')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

now = datetime.datetime.now()


draw.text((650, 450),'                      CURRENT GRADES' )
draw.text((650, 500), 'Period 1: Geography -----------------------------')#First Grade
draw.text((650, 550), 'Period 2: Francais-------------------------------')#Second Grade
draw.text((650, 600), 'Period 3: Science--------------------------------')#Third Grade
draw.text((650, 650), 'Period 4: P.E------------------------------------')#Fourth Grade
draw.text((650, 700), 'Period 5: Algebra 9------------------------------')#Fifth Grade
draw.text((650, 750), 'Period 6: LA-------------------------------------')Sixth grade
draw.text((650, 800), 'Last Updated: {0}'.format(now))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save('mod_bg.bmp')
```

when the grades are returned i need them to be put into each class

if any info is needed ask
thanks

Comment: Your question is how to put the data from `cell.text` onto the image? What's wrong with your code exactly?

Comment: i need each grade separated and put into each subject as a variable but i dont know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having difficulty getting the data out of the string `cell.text` then you might want something like the following.

I've put the data into a string to start with so that we have a self-contained test:

```
grades = """--
B
84
--
A-
90
--
C+
79
--
A
95
--
B
82
--
B
81"""

gradesList = grades.split('\n')
letterGrade = gradesList[1::3]
pctGrade = [int(x) for x in gradesList[2::3]]

for i in range(len(letterGrade)):
    print ("%s\t%d" % (letterGrade[i],pctGrade[i]))
```

... and I'm printing the result to the console rather than putting it into the image, but @TankorSmash has shown how to do the latter part.

The output from this program is:

```
B       84
A-      90
C+      79
A       95
B       82
B       81
```

For more information on splitting multi-line strings, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172439/how-do-i-split-a-mult-line-string-into-multiple-lines). For more information on slicing lists with three limits, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list).

Comment: thats not always going to be the data though it changes when the grades are updated so i need to take each number and assign a variable for each grade

Comment: You would just want to do the same thing with `cell.text`, as it is acquired from the school grade site, as I have done with `grades` in my program, i.e. `gradesList = cell.text.split('\n')`. The reason I didn't do that was to make my program a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: its telling me the list index is out of range ?

Comment: You would get an "index out of range" at either the line `letterGrade = gradesList[1::3]` or `pctGrade = [int(x) for x in gradesList[2::3]]` if `gradesList` had fewer than 2 elements. If you try `print gradesList` before those lines, that should confirm that has the required number of elements. If `gradesList` does not contain the list that you expect, try `print cell.text` to be sure that it actually contains the items you expect, each on a separate line. I haven't used Selenium (which I think is what you are using?) so I'm going by your description of the `cell.text` format.

Answer (score 1):

Without writing out the code for you, you'll need to:

- Iterate over the `cell.text` in the same order as the list of Periods you've got
- Fill the space between the `cell.text` and the  `Period 5:...` stuff with the `----` fill string you've got so it's always the same length
- Draw the text at a location that increments by 50 every time you iterate over `cell.text`.
- Save the image.