# How to grab first line url from a remote PHP response string using Python?

Tags: python

I want to extract a URL from a remote PHP response. My current code gets the link variable response, but how can I only a grab the first line of the response, which in this case is a URL?

URL to look in first line of PHP response in link variable:

```
http://test.awebsite.com/1.m3u8?token=454766879809809
```

Python code:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.somesite.com/test.php')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)   
link = response.read()
```

Full PHP response using `print link`:

```
10:01:08 T:7688  NOTICE: 
    http://test.awebsite.com/1.m3u8?token=454766879809809 
    <!-- Start -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://3.js"></script>
    <noscript><br><center><font color='#000000' face='Verdana' style='font-size: 11px; background-color:#FFFFFF'><a target='_blank' href='http://www.ads.com'><font color='#000000'>ads</font></a></font></center></noscript>
    <!-- End -->
```

Comment: The URL you ask for seems to be on the 2nd line. Check my updated answer for this....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a mult-line string into multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172439/how-do-i-split-a-mult-line-string-into-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try splitting the response by lines like this:

```
lines = link.split("\n")
```

And then get the first line:

```
anwser = lines[1] # 1st line is lines[0], 2nd is lines[1], 3rd is lines[2] etc...
```

**Note** that you should expect an exception to be raised if the substring you split at isn't in your string. One way you can check it like this:

```
first_line=""
if "\n" in link:
    first_line = link.split("\n")[1] # Gets the same result as before in one line...
else:
    print("Something went wrong...")
print(first_line)
```

Or with a try-except statement:

```
first_line=""
try:
    first_line = link.split("\n")[1]
except IndexError:
    print("Something went wrong...")
print(first_line)
```

I hope that answers your question!

Comment: Thanks for reply . I tried the first two line of your code and i get this error:Error Contents: global name 'answer' is not defined

Comment: Are you using the anwser variable in an if or a loop? You might need to declare it before the if by writing: answer = ""
Otherwise, if you try to use it outside this if/loop, you will get this error.

Comment: See the updated anwser (the part with the if statement) for an example of what you might need to do...

Comment: I edited my first post. i still getting empty data for first line. I am running this code in kodi and my print link shows response as first post(in kodi log). could you see the response and tell me why i can't grab that first line ?

Comment: @ant0nisk: *Note that it is a good practice to check if the character you split is in your string!* -- I'd argue otherwise. What's the point of writing more code to write out vague error message?

Comment: Yes, of course he could use a try-except statement. What I wanted to say here is that he should expect Exceptions to be raised in some cases. Sorry I didn't make that clear, I will edit my answer...

Comment: Many thanks . The data was in second line as you mentioned it is working now ! In the browser it was showing in first line for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I decided to clarify some things missed in [ant0nisk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33962266/3821804) by editing it, but I ended up completely rewriting it, so I decided to post it as separate answer.</sub>

You can try [splitting the response by lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/172439/3821804) like this:

```
lines = link.splitlines()
```

And then get the first line:

```
anwser = lines[1] # 1st line is lines[0], 2nd is lines[1], 3rd is lines[2] etc...
```

Note that if `link` is made up from less than two lines, the line above raises raise `IndexError` exception, which (if unhandled) will terminate your program with message which will be meaningful for you, but might confuse non-programmers. If you for example want folks-friendly error message or have plan B what to do in case of one-line or empty request, you can handle the error with a try-except statement:

```
try:
    first_line = link.split("\n")[1]
except IndexError:
    print("Response is too short! (expected at least 2 lines)")
else: # Everything OK
    print(first_line)
```

Catching exception is expensive. Usually it is not a problem, because it happens when recovering from *exceptional* scenarios. But, if exception is raised often, so that handling it is not an exceptional scenario, using `if` instead of `try-except` *might* turn out to be faster.