# Paramiko recv output generating all the commands output and expecting only last command output

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using paramiko for ssh interfactive shell for switches.

Below is the sample example code (Note complete code):

```
remote_conn.send("\n")
remote_conn.send("show version")
# Wait for the command to complete
#time.sleep(1)
remote_conn.send("\n")
remote_conn.send("show interface brief")
# Wait for the command to complete
time.sleep(3)
if remote_conn.recv_ready():
    sp_detail = remote_conn.recv(5000)
print(sp_detail)
```

recv command print both show version output and show interface brief.

How do i get only show interface brief output to variable sp_detail

I referred below link and used if statement  same way they used but still i am getting all the commands output.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094461/paramiko-capturing-command-output)

Please help

Comment: that's how paramiko (actually ssh) works. you have to filter out the information you're not interested in.

Comment: ok let me filter it