# Can't split multi-line string into an array of rows

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, split

I'm very new to Python and just ran into a problem.

I tried many solutions suggested (mostly from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172439/how-do-i-split-a-multi-line-string-into-multiple-lines) question) on making every line of a .txt document into an array object. I tried using just `split()`, `split("\n")` and `splitlines()`, but none of them work. Every line in the text document is a number and it will do some calculations on it. For example the first line is **50**, but it does the first calculation on the number **5**, second one on the number **0** and on the next one it throws an error about being unable to convert it into a float (*ValueError: could not convert string to float*), probably cause it tried to convert **\n** or something.

Here is the code:

```
def weightTest(f, minWeight, fti):
    weights = []
    f_content = open(f, encoding='UTF-8')
    for row in f_content:
        length = row.splitlines()
        for length in row:
            weight = float(length) ** 3 * fti / 100 # ValueError
            if weight < minWeight:
                print("Smaller than the minimum weight.")
            else:
                print("The weight is " + str(weight) + " grams.")
                weights.append(weight)
    print("The biggest weight: " + str(max(weights)) + " kg")
    f_content.close()
f = input("Insert file name: ")
alam = float(input("Insert minimum weight: "))
fti = float(input("Insert FTI: "))
weightTest(f, alam, fti)
```

Here is the text used (instead of spaces, there's new lines, StackOverflow doesn't want to show them somewhy):
50
70
75
55
54
80

Here is the log:

```
Insert file name: kalakaalud.txt
Insert minimum weight: 50
Insert FTI: 0.19
Smaller than the minimum weight.
Smaller than the minimum weight.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\File\Location\kalakaal.py", line 18, in <module>
    weightTest(f, minWeight, fti)
  File "C:\File\Location\kalakaal.py", line 7, in weightTest
    weight = float(length) ** 3 * fti / 100
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: Please post an exemple of the data you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `for row in f_content:`, you will get each line as something like `"4\n"`. When you then use `.splitlines()`, you are getting `["4", ""]`. The 4 can be converted just fine, but there is no way to convert a blank string to a float. Instead, don't do your `for length in row:`; just use `row` directly; `float()` doesn't mind the newline character:

```
>>> x = '4\n'
>>> float(x)
4.0
>>> first, second = x.splitlines()
>>> first
'4'
>>> second
''
>>> float(first)
4.0
>>> float(second)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

That would make your loop look like this:

```
for length in f_content:
    weight = float(length) ** 3 * fti / 100 # ValueError
    if weight < minWeight:
        print("Smaller than the minimum weight.")
    else:
        print("The weight is " + str(weight) + " grams.")
        weights.append(weight)
```

I changed `for row in f_content` to `for length in f_content` so that I didn't need to replace all occurrences of `length` with `row`.

Comment: I tried it, but it wouldn't work. Could you please provide an example? I don't get an error anymore, but it just shows the output for only the first number now and then does nothing.

Comment: @ThomasTom: I edited to show what your code should look like now. Does that work?