# How to access the nth line of a multiline variable in python

Tags: python, variables, multiline

Given a multiple line variables

```
var="""this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4"""
```

How can I assign to a variable a specific line, say line 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a multi-line string into multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172439/how-do-i-split-a-multi-line-string-into-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> var="""this is line 1
... this is line 2
... this is line 3
... this is line 4"""
>>> 
>>> line3 = var.splitlines()[3 - 1]
>>> line3
'this is line 3'
```

`str.splitlines` splits your multiline-string into distinct lines. line `n` will be at index `n - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to split with "\n" char like that

```
>>> a = """this is line1
... this is line2
... this is line3"""
>>> a
'this is line1\nthis is line2\nthis is line3'
>>> a.split("\n")[1]
'this is line2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have n-1 new line character between n lines. Suppose you have 3 lines so you have 2 new line characters.

```
multiple_lines ="""this is line 1
... this is line 2
... this is line 3
... this is line 4"""
ans=multiple_lines.split(“\n”)[m-1]
```

suppose you want to take the mth string from that multiple strings.  m-1 because indexing starts from 0, so you if you want to access the 3rd element you will have to do ans[2]