# Need text between each br tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
driver.get('https://cogos.com/locations')
y = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class= 'address']")

for a in y:
    b = a.text
    print(b)
```

Returning:

```
CoGo’s 450 BP
1610 Gringo Road
Aliquippa
663.07 Miles.
CoGo’s 497 BP
2399 Duss Avenue
Ambridge
666.93 Miles.
CoGo’s 463 BP
1907 Darlington Road
Beaver Falls
668.64 Miles.
CoGo’s 30 Sunoco
6371 Lincoln Highway
Bedford
719.65 Miles.
CoGo’s 809 Exxon
5100 State Route 51
Belle Vernon
667.74 Miles.
```

Comment: You are able to extract all the 4 parts of the total text as in `CoGo’s 450 BP`, `1610 Gringo Road`, `Aliquippa` and `663.07 Miles`. Are you expecting something else?

Comment: @DebanjanB I needed to add each line into a separate row of a csv file.

Comment: can you provide an example of how your csv file should look like?

Answer (score 0):

As an option I'd recommend here: 
extract in the way You do: 
Do the extraction by Xpath:

```
//*[@class= 'address']/p
```

And for each piece of text extracted - split by break-line symbol.
[image: html tree view of the page]

Per [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/172454/1546574)  -

```
inputString.splitlines()
```

Should do the trick;

So in Your case

```
driver.get('https://cogos.com/locations')
y = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@class= 'address']/p")

for a in y:
    b = a.text
    x = b.splitlines()
    print(x)
```

Hope this be helpful for You.
Regards,