# Format a raw API Response

Tags: python, string

I am writing a program that gets some data from an API, the response is simple text (no JSON or XML), since the data is in plain text, it also contains escape sequences like `\n` and `\r`

[image]

Here's the data as printed by postman.
When I try to split the lines using `.split(":")`, the escape sequences get in the way.

Here's the code:

```
def getSuffix(password):
     api_resp = get(f"https://api.pwnedpasswords.com/range/{prefix}")
     api_resp = api_resp.text
     print(api_resp.split(":"))
```

and here's what I get:
[image]

I've tried using `.strip("\r\n")` as well, but it does not seem to work.

Here's the desired output:
[image]

I want the string and the number associated be in a list and this list to be a part of another list.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get as a result instead? Please show a smaller example as actual text, not as images.

Comment: If you want to split the lines, why do you not use the `splitlines` string method?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I was not aware that such a method existed, this seems to solve my problem, thanks a ton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a multi-line string into multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172439/how-do-i-split-a-multi-line-string-into-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) for suggesting the `.splitlines()` method. It seems to fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to apply all the operations over the complete text instead of lines. The reason `.strip("\r\n")` did not work is because it strips the characters from leading and trailing places of the complete text.You can use `.replace("\r\n","")` for the removal and then process the text using `.split(":")` for every line as mentioned by @mkrieger1