# How to split text into separate lines?

Tags: python, string

I have this text and i need to split it into separate lines:

```
text = """
| Post code | Cost, thousands USD  |
|-----------+----------------------|
| 33022     |                0.543 |
| 33145     |             9563.214 |
| 33658     |               85.543 |
| 33854     |                0.010 |
| 33698     |          1000000.000 |
"""
```

expecting output with 7 separate lines or list with seven elements that include a single line

Comment: `text.strip().splitlines()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a multi-line string into multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172439/how-do-i-split-a-multi-line-string-into-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be to split this string by "\n" and to reference only the lines where are the values and split them by "|", removing additional spaces to add each item in a tuple.

```
text = """
| Post code | Cost, thousands USD  |
|-----------+----------------------|
| 33022     |                0.543 |
| 33145     |             9563.214 |
| 33658     |               85.543 |
| 33854     |                0.010 |
| 33698     |          1000000.000 |
"""

records = []

for i in text.strip().split("\n")[2:]:
    row = i[3:-2].split("|")
    values = tuple(j.strip() for j in row)
    records.append(values)
```

With this, records will be equals to a list of tuples where each value is a column:

```
[('3022', '0.543'),
 ('3145', '9563.214'),
 ('3658', '85.543'),
 ('3854', '0.010'),
 ('3698', '1000000.000')]
```

If you want an one-line solution:

```
records = [tuple(j.strip() for j in i[3:-2].split("|")) for i in text.strip().split("\n")[2:]]
```

If you want to keep the headers:

```
headers = [tuple(i.strip() for i in text.strip().split("\n")[0][1:-1].split("|"))]
records = headers + records
```